# Remove element from itertools.combinations while iterating?

Tags: python, iterator, combinations

Given a list `l` and all combinations of the list elements is it possible to remove any combination containing `x` while iterating over all combinations, so that you never consider a combination containing `x` during the iteration after it is removed?

```
for a, b in itertools.combinations(l, 2):
    if some_function(a,b):
        remove_any_tup_with_a_or_b(a, b)
```

My list `l` is pretty big so I don't want to keep the combinations in memory.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I think the comment on "I don't want to keep the combinations in memory" was saying that the simple solution of creating a `list` (or some other data structure) of all the combinations, so you can remove the "bad" combinations from later in the `list` as soon as they're identified, would not be suitable. Most people who even know about `itertools` realize how generators work (avoiding up front memory costs).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Oh, ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cheap trick to accomplish this would be to filter by disjoint testing using a dynamically updated `set` of exclusion values, but it wouldn't actually avoid generating the combinations you wish to exclude, so it's not a major performance benefit (though `filter`ing using a C built-in function like `isdisjoint` will be faster than Python level `if` checks with `continue` statements typically, by pushing the `filter` work to the C layer):

```
from future_builtins import filter  # Only on Py2, for generator based filter
import itertools

blacklist = set()
for a, b in filter(blacklist.isdisjoint, itertools.combinations(l, 2)):
    if some_function(a,b):
        blacklist.update((a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all tuples containing the number `x` from the list of combinations `itertools.combinations(l, 2)`, consider that you there is a one-to-one mapping (mathematically speaking) from the set `itertools.combinations([i for i in range(1,len(l)], 2)` to the `itertools.combinations(l, 2)` that **don't** contain the number `x`.

**Example:**

The set of all of combinations from `itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4], 2)` that don't contain the number 1 is given by `[(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]`. Notice that the number of elements in this list is equal to the number of elements of combinations in the list `itertools.combinations([1,2,3], 2)=[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]`.

Since order doesn't matter in combinations, you can map 1 to 4 in `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]` to get `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]=[(4, 2), (4, 3), (2, 3)]=[(2, 4), (3, 4), (2, 3)]=[(2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]`.